# Using Regular Expression to block domain

Tags: php, regex

I'm creating a blacklist and I want to block ALL variations of a given URL. For example,

```
www.google.com
google.com
google.com/maps
sub.google.com
google.com/dir/dir2/dir3
```

I know next to nothing about RegEx, so far I have this feeble attempt:

```
$blacklist = array(
'\.google.\\',
);
```

Can someone help me out?

EDIT:

I'd also like to block ALL domain with specific extensions such as 
    .me
    .xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just doing a pre_match you probably just need something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$subject = "somedomain";
$pattern = '/\.google\./';
if(preg_match($pattern, $subject)){
    die('blacklisted');
}
?>
```

Comment: And to block all domains with (say) extension `.me`, use '/\.me\b/'

Comment: after adding your RegEx, I have `$blacklist = array(
    '/\.google\./',
);` and `$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
            if (preg_match($host, $GLOBALS['blacklist'])) {
                return false;
            }` But it's returning true instead of false

Comment: I think you have your pattern and blacklist array backwards, it's needle haystack not the other way in this function.

Comment: as in it's `preg_match($GLOBALS['blacklist'],$host);` not the other way round.

Comment: You can't pass an array into preg_match, it has to be a string according to the documentation: http://uk.php.net/preg_match_all

Comment: oh, well that makes sense :) Thanks for finding that! What else can I use other than `preg_match`? I need the array.

Comment: You'll have to loop over the array to do the matching. If you find one just return false to prevent the loop going through all the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you ONLY want to block the domains then why not simply use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) Its really good and faster then regex match for simple pattern matching.. Check out the link

```
$domain_name = "www.maps.google.com";
if(strpos($domain_name,"google") > 1)
    do sumthing here
else
    do sumthing
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: what if the domain is maps.googles.com? Note the added `s` at the end. Will it return a false positive?

Comment: Paul bro googles.com and google.com are both different domains. As the question says user wants to block all VARIATIONS in domain not the domain itself